# Using .NET Activator.CreateInstance without using DTO

Tags: .net, dto, activator, createinstance

I have a Form class that contains several custom Form Elements.

I have an Entity object, that provides specific attributes for the element, these are parsed from on XML file.  All elements take the Entity as a parameter in their constructor, but then require different parameters in their constructor after that.

For the element creation I am current using a switch statement as below.  However, I want to convert this to use Activator.CreateInstance.  However, with different parameters in the constructor the only way I know of to handle this is to create a DTO that contains all parameters, pass it in the constructor and then have each constructor request whatever information it requires.  I want an alternative as it is my understanding that DTO is frowned upon in modern implmentations.

```
        switch (entity.GetPropertyValue("Class"))
        {
            case "FormCheckBox":
                newElement = new FormCheckBox(entity, BaseElementHeight);
                break;
            case "RowSeparator":
                newElement = new RowSeperator(entity, RowHeight, _mainCanvas);
                break;
            case "FormLabel":
                newElement = new FormLabel(entity, BaseElementHeight);
                break;
            case "FormEditBox":
                newElement = new FormEditBox(entity, _mainCanvas);//, BaseElementHeight, 600);
                break;
            case "FormComboBox":
                newElement = new FormComboBox(entity, BaseElementHeight);
                break;
            case "FormTextBox":
                newElement = new FormTextBox(entity, BaseElementHeight, TextFontSize, MaxFontBoxSize);
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
```

Does anyone have thoughts and/or ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

rather than inject every thing into the entity's ctor, why not use the [command pattern](http://www.google.com/search?q=command+pattern) or 
[double dispatch pattern](http://www.google.com/search?q=double+dispatch+pattern)
to manage this.

Instead of passing the entity as a ctor argument, make it a property, or just pass the properties that are needed.

```
new FormCheckBox
{
   Height = BaseElementHeight,
   Number = entity.Number, 
   Text = entity.Text 
   ...
};
```

This keeps the entity out of the UI completely.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your first statement?  Regarding your second statement, my entities don't have any UI code.  In fact my entities really only know about their data and the relationships to other entities.  I have a general method of my entity classes call GetPropertyValue, similar to GetAttribute in XML.  Inside the form elements, which are my UI, they accept an entity reference and query it to find out information that it needs to know in order to render and behave properly.

Comment: the `visitor pattern` may be more appropriate, but the same concepts apply. keep the entity out of the ui.

Comment: Thank you.  In my case some of the form elements may have to access up to 20 properties of the entity.  The entity may contain data such as validation type, input mask, mandatory, max num chars, min num chars, and read only just to name a few.  I guess a DTO may be appropriate here.  There is also parameters than have to be passed in that are not entity properties, such as height, which is determined by the consuming form.

Comment: it sounds like the entity itself has too much responsibility. i would find a way to extract and encapsulate the validation requirements into it's own component, or collection of components.

Comment: Also, in the approach you are describing, how can this allow me to use the Activator.CreateInstance method?  The other part of my issue is that my elements have different ctors.  Should I come up with one master parameter list that every object uses, some parameters of which it will just ignore, or should I juse continue to use the switch statement.  I do still have to add about 6 more form element types, so the switch with get lengthy and I want to avoid the maintainence of it.

Comment: I also believe this is where the UI requirements are bleeding into the domain. the domain shouldn't care how the data is validated, only that the data it receives is valid. and this can be controlled through the design of the domain, not a list of validators.

Comment: I really appreciate your insight.  Any way we could take this offline?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6062/discussion-between-jason-meckley-and-wpfnewbie)

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to pass the parameter on the constructor? If not I would suggest to create the object by naming convention ( as your case show that is possible ) and then , by using always a convention, via reflection set each property. Since the value you have in the XML is always a string, you probably want to pass it in a Convert.ChangeType() to the target property type to have a graceful working assignment.

Comment: we are in chat if you would like to join us.